# How to create daily checklist

Tags: task-list

Question for Sharepoint (SP) 2010 out-of-the-box or via SP Designer. I have 20+ tasks that's done by a team, recurring everyday, each with an assignee and due time. I want this checklist to do the following. Anyone has solution for this?
  -New checklist gets created everyday, automatically.
  -If a task is overdue, assigned person and his/her manager gets a reminder email.
  -Once every tasks on the checklist is completed, SP sends an End-Of-Day email to manager.
  -Completed (or not), checklist from previous day gets saved and archived for future reference, so any comments made to an item is retained for future reference.

Not all described above need be satisfied, but at least I'd like for a recurring checklist to be produced everyday automatically.

Any input is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to setup the eod checklist, I am also looking to do the same, any help would be appreciated. cheers